# Access window out of range in RasterIO(). Requested (0,0) of size 232x608 on raster of 231x608

Tags: python, raster, clip

I'm trying to clip one raster by the other to have the same size.
I use this code to do so :

```
IMG1 = gdal.Open("C:/Users/aurel/Downloads/2013-10-26.tif")
IMG2 = gdal.Open("C:/Users/aurel/Downloads/2013-10-26 (2).tif")
#IN ORDER TO CLIP BY EXTENT EVERY IMAGE
    gt1=IMG1.GetGeoTransform()
    gt2=IMG2.GetGeoTransform()
    if gt1[0] < gt2[0]: #CONDITIONAL TO SELECT THE CORRECT ORIGIN
        gt3=gt2[0]
    else:
        gt3=gt1[0]
    if gt1[3] < gt2[3]:
        gt4=gt1[3]
    else:
        gt4=gt2[3]
    xOrigin = gt3
    yOrigin = gt4
    pixelWidth = gt1[1]
    pixelHeight = gt1[5]

    r1 = [gt1[0], gt1[3],gt1[0] + (gt1[1] * IMG1.RasterXSize), gt1[3] + (gt1[5] * IMG1.RasterYSize)]
    r2 = [gt2[0], gt2[3],gt2[0] + (gt2[1] * IMG2.RasterXSize), gt2[3] + (gt2[5] * IMG2.RasterYSize)]
    intersection = [max(r1[0], r2[0]), min(r1[1], r2[1]), min(r1[2], r2[2]), max(r1[3], r2[3])]

    xmin = intersection[0]
    xmax = intersection[2]
    ymin = intersection[3]
    ymax = intersection[1]

    # Specify offset and rows and columns to read
    xoff = int((xmin - xOrigin)/pixelWidth)
    yoff = int((yOrigin - ymax)/pixelWidth)
    xcount = int((xmax - xmin)/pixelWidth)+1
    ycount = int((ymax - ymin)/pixelWidth)+1
    srs=IMG1.GetProjectionRef() #necessary to export with SRS

    target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM').Create('', xcount, ycount, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
    target_ds.SetGeoTransform((xmin, pixelWidth, 0,ymax, 0, pixelHeight,))


    img1 = IMG1.ReadAsArray(xoff, yoff, xcount, ycount)  
    img2 = IMG2.ReadAsArray(xoff, yoff, xcount, ycount)
```

But I got the following error : Access window out of range in RasterIO().  Requested (0,0) of size 232x608 on raster of 231x608.

Could this issue come from the fact that xoff and yoff are equals to 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems really complicated for a thing that already exists out there.

If you can, try to use [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead (more modern and more pythonic way of using gdal), this will simplify your life!

You can derive the extent of your images with `ds.bounds`, create vectors from it with [`shapely.box`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.box.html) and intersect them with [`geopandas`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/set_operations.html) if you want.

The go back to your pixel space with rasterio, and leverage the [`Window`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/windowed-rw.html) class to have a more readable code.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to clip a raster by the other way more easier in Rstudio :

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

r2 = raster("C:/Users/aurel/Downloads/2013-10-26.tif")
r1 = raster("C:/Users/aurel/Downloads/2013-10-26 (2).tif")

test = crop(r1,r2)
test2 = crop(r2, r1)
rtest = resample(test, test2, "bilinear")
```